# Azure web job continuous peeking multiple messages at one time

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, appservice

I have written a web job in my project. I am using continuous WEBJOBS for queue trigger. web job is working properly but some time it is giving two output for one queue. I think one queue is running multiple times.

Previously I am using TRIGERED WEBJOB but they are aborting automatically. so i converted to continuous triggered WEBJOB but now facing this issue any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean processing the same message twice? If so, this is expected since queues in general guarantee *at least once* delivery.

If you need to process each message *exactly once*, you should add a check in your implementation to ensure messages aren't processed multiple times.